# rbindlist a small number of large data.table s

Tags: r, memory-management, data.table

I have a list of 31 `data.table`s

```
List31 <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "^[0-9]?[0-9]\\.csv$"), fread, na.strings = c("*", "", "NA"))

Read 3562435 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.335 GB file in 00:00:06
Read 4567456 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.412 GB file in 00:00:08
Read 4626490 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.418 GB file in 00:00:07
Read 4705069 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.427 GB file in 00:00:08
Read 4857572 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.450 GB file in 00:00:08
Read 5111313 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.497 GB file in 00:00:09
Read 5275920 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.515 GB file in 00:00:09
Read 5306365 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.518 GB file in 00:00:09
Read 5354296 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.799 GB file in 00:00:15
Read 5499375 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.826 GB file in 00:00:16
Read 5795744 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.897 GB file in 00:00:17
Read 3773471 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.355 GB file in 00:00:06
Read 6059535 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.897 GB file in 00:00:17
Read 5354296 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.794 GB file in 00:00:14
Read 5499375 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.821 GB file in 00:00:14
Read 5795744 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.891 GB file in 00:00:18
Read 6059535 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.891 GB file in 00:00:15
Read 6533038 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.962 GB file in 00:00:19
Read 6975097 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 1.066 GB file in 00:00:19
Read 7191321 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 1.099 GB file in 00:00:23
Read 7436464 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 1.139 GB file in 00:00:21
Read 7698811 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 1.181 GB file in 00:00:21
Read 4165634 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.393 GB file in 00:00:07
Read 7935997 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 1.218 GB file in 00:00:25
Read 8226535 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 1.264 GB file in 00:00:23
Read 4172169 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.393 GB file in 00:00:06
Read 4132907 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.390 GB file in 00:00:06
Read 4114118 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.389 GB file in 00:00:11
Read 4182943 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.396 GB file in 00:00:07
Read 4348032 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.391 GB file in 00:00:07
Read 4486031 rows and 47 (of 47) columns from 0.404 GB file in 00:00:07
```

comprising 21.6 GB on disk and about 27 GB in memory. My machine has 64 GB RAM; however, when I attempt to `rbindlist(List31, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)`, I run out memory

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 650.0 Mb
```

What's the best strategy for my given machine? (I can't use AWS etc.)

1. I tried increasing the swap file. I am working on Windows 10 and tried increasing the virtual memory, but it seemed to offer no benefit.

Manually filling `NA`s for missing column in each element of the list and then using `use.names = FALSE, fill = FALSE`. I tried the following but got the same error.

```
library(magrittr)
names_by_class <-
  lapply(List31, function(DT){
    vapply(DT, class, character(1))
  }) %>%
  unlist %>%
  {
    data.table(name = names(.),
               class = .)
  } %>%
  unique

List31_names <- 
  lapply(List31, names) %>%
  unlist %>% 
  unique

ii <- 1
add_nas <- function(DT){
  for (j in setdiff(List31_names, names(DT))){
    # Look up class:
    classes <- names_by_class[name == j][["class"]]
    if (length(classes) > 1){
      if (any(classes == "character")){
        classes <- "character"
      } else {
        if (any(classes == "numeric")){
          classes <- "numeric"
        } else {
          if (any(classes == "integer")){
            classes <- "integer"
          } else {
            classes <- "logical"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    switch(classes,
           "integer" = {
             DT[, (j) := NA_integer_]
           },
           "character" = {
             DT[, (j) := NA_character_]
           }, 
           "numeric" = {
             DT[, (j) := NA_real_]
           }, 
           "logical" = {
             DT[, (j) := NA]
           })

  }
  fwrite(DT, paste0(ii, ".csv"))
}
for (i in seq_along(List31)){
  add_nas(List31[[i]])
  ii <- ii + 1
}
```

Cardinality of column types:

```
1   integer    32
2 character    11
3   numeric     4
```

Comment: I would take a look at the ff (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html) and bigmemory R packages (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/bigmemory.pdf), they might be useful for these kind of things.

Comment: Not the most elegant: maybe do not create `List31` at first, instead loop over `list.files()`, `fread()` a file, `rbind()` then `rm()` it (and possibly `gc()` though it's supposed to be unnecessary) before the next iteration

Comment: For the 27GB to fit in your 64GB RAM, `fread` would need to quick scan all the files first and allocate the final result up front to avoid reading each file first; i.e. `fread` would accept the vector of file names directly in a single call. Linked back from existing [FR#586](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/586) to here.